# Create new Excel Sheet with SQL Server OPENROWSET

Tags: sql-server, excel, openrowset, aceoledb

I need to write data to a new Excel sheet in an existing Excel file, with T-SQL.

I need to use ACE OLEDB and `OPENROWSET` statement.

Usually, I write from a table to an existing Excel sheet, with:

```
INSERT INTO OPENROWSET (
  'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 
  'Excel 12.0;Database=c:\myExcelFile.xlsx;'
  'SELECT Col_A, Col_B, Col_C FROM [SheetName$]')
    SELECT Col_A, Col_B, Col_C 
    FROM dbo.MyTable
```

The code above works only for an existing sheet, which has 3 columns, and the names Col_A, Col_B, Col_C in the first row.

I've tried to modify the `OPENROWSET` statement using a `[SheetName$]` that don't exists. I've tried with or without `$` characters, with column names or with `*` wildcard, but nothing worked.

Thanks

Comment: This really isn't what these tools are designed for. I strongly suggest using *something else* for this. Powershell, a Macro, an ETL tool, just *not* T-SQL.

Comment: Agreed with @Thom A. I think this could be much simpler if you set up an Excel sheet to pull the data from SQL.

Comment: I think one can create a linked server which is a excel file and then create sheets, but this is very arcane stuff. While i do love to solve all my issues in sql server, some things are better to be done outside of it

Comment: Take a peek at something like https://spreadsheetlight.com/

Comment: I can not install libraries to the server, nor add SQL connection to Excel file, nor install SSIS. I know ACE OleDb is not the best way but I have many restrictions. Anyway, it seems ACE OleDB can generate sheets&columns,  (e.g. as it is used by SSIS) but I don't know the right instructions.